# Beginner needs help mono on os x 10.8.4

Tags: mono, monomac

I'm a complete beginner at all of this so you may have to bear with me. I'm using a mac os x 10.8.4 and I want to run a windows exe file on my mac using mono. When I try to run any program I get the same error and I don't know what it means. Here's the first paragraph of the message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
```

Could anyone tell me what this means and how to fix it? And please let me know if I can give more information to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this [issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7962). Try installing [X11](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).